Issue in inserting data in database using string query
In this when I try to insert the data it absolutely inserts the data in database tables, but in the tblTransaction table the data is not inserting.
This is the SaleEntry.cs file to handle the insertion (C# Code)
public class SaleEntry
{
    private CloudErpVEntities db = new CloudErpVEntities();

    public string selectcustomerid = string.Empty;
    DataTable dtEntries = null;
    public string ConfirmSale(int CompanyID, int BranchID, int UserID, string InvoiceNo, string CustomerInvoiceID, float Amount, string CustomerID, string Customername, bool isPayment)
    {
        try
        {
            dtEntries = null;
            string saletitle = "Sale To " + Customername.Trim();
            var financialCheck = DatabaseQuery.Retrive("select top 1 FinancialYearID from tblFinancialYear where IsActive = 1");
            string FinancialYearID = (financialCheck != null ? Convert.ToString(financialCheck.Rows[0][0]) : string.Empty);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FinancialYearID))
            {
                return "Your Company Financial Year is not Set Please Contact to Adminstrator!";
            }`

            string successmessage = "Sale Success";

            string AccountHeadID = string.Empty;
            string AccountControlID = string.Empty;
            string AccountSubControlID = string.Empty;

            var saleAccount = db.tblAccountSettings.Where(a => a.AccountActivityID == 5 && a.CompanyID == CompanyID && a.BranchID == BranchID).FirstOrDefault();
            //Credit Entry Sale
            AccountHeadID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountHeadID);
            AccountControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountControlID);
            AccountSubControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountSubControlID);

            string transectiontitle = string.Empty;

            transectiontitle = "Sale To " + Customername.Trim();
            //SetEntries(FinancialYearID, AccountHeadID, AccountControlID, AccountSubControlID, InvoiceNo, UserID.ToString(), "0", Convert.ToString(Amount), DateTime.Now, transectiontitle);
            SetEntries(FinancialYearID, AccountHeadID, AccountSubControlID, AccountSubControlID, CompanyID.ToString(), BranchID.ToString(), InvoiceNo, UserID.ToString(), Convert.ToString(Amount), "0", DateTime.Now, transectiontitle);


            //Debit Entry Sale
            saleAccount = db.tblAccountSettings.Where(a => a.AccountActivityID == 8 && a.CompanyID == CompanyID && a.BranchID == BranchID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (saleAccount == null)
            {
                return "Sale Account (i.e. Sale Payment Pending/Succeed) not found in your <b>Account Flow</b>.";
            }
            AccountHeadID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountHeadID);
            AccountControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountControlID);
            AccountSubControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountSubControlID);

            transectiontitle = Customername.Trim() + " , Sale Payment is Pending!";
            //SetEntries(FinancialYearID, AccountHeadID, AccountControlID, AccountSubControlID, InvoiceNo, UserID.ToString(), "0", Convert.ToString(Amount), DateTime.Now, transectiontitle);
            SetEntries(FinancialYearID, AccountHeadID, AccountSubControlID, AccountSubControlID, CompanyID.ToString(), BranchID.ToString(), InvoiceNo, UserID.ToString(), "0", Convert.ToString(Amount),  DateTime.Now, transectiontitle);

            if (isPayment == true)
            {
                string payinvoicenno = "INP" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

                saleAccount = db.tblAccountSettings.Where(a => a.AccountActivityID == 8 && a.CompanyID == CompanyID && a.BranchID == BranchID).FirstOrDefault();
                AccountHeadID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountHeadID);
                AccountControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountControlID);
                AccountSubControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountSubControlID);

                transectiontitle = "Sale Payment Paid By " + Customername;
                SetEntries(FinancialYearID, AccountHeadID, AccountSubControlID, AccountSubControlID, CompanyID.ToString(), BranchID.ToString(), payinvoicenno, UserID.ToString(), Convert.ToString(Amount), "0", DateTime.Now, transectiontitle);

                saleAccount = db.tblAccountSettings.Where(a => a.AccountActivityID == 12 && a.CompanyID == CompanyID && a.BranchID == BranchID).FirstOrDefault();
                AccountHeadID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountHeadID);
                AccountControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountControlID);
                AccountSubControlID = Convert.ToString(saleAccount.AccountSubControlID);
                transectiontitle = Customername + " , Sale Payment is Succesed!";
                SetEntries(FinancialYearID, AccountHeadID, AccountControlID, AccountSubControlID, CompanyID.ToString(), BranchID.ToString(), payinvoicenno, UserID.ToString(), "0", Convert.ToString(Amount), DateTime.Now, transectiontitle);

                string paymentquery = string.Format("insert into tblCustomerPayment(CustomerID,CustomerInvoiceID,UserID,invoiceNo,TotalAmount,PaidAmount,RemainingBalance,CompanyID,BranchID) " +
                "values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')",
                CustomerID, CustomerInvoiceID, UserID, payinvoicenno, Amount, Amount, "0", CompanyID, BranchID);
                DatabaseQuery.Insert(paymentquery);

                successmessage = successmessage + " with Payment.";
            }

            foreach (DataRow entryrow in dtEntries.Rows)
            {
                string entryquery = string.Format("insert into tblTransaction(FinancialYearID,AccountHeadID,AccountControlID,AccountSubControlID,UserID,InvoiceNo,Credit,Debit,TransectionDate,TransactionTitle,CompanyID,BranchID) " +
                                    "values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')",
                                    Convert.ToString(entryrow[0]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[1]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[2]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[3]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[4]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[5]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[6]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[7]), (entryrow[8]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[9]), CompanyID, BranchID);
                DatabaseQuery.Insert(entryquery);
            }

            return successmessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return $"Unexpected Error: {ex.Message}. Please try Again!";
        }
    }

    private void SetEntries(
        string FinancialYearID, string AccountControlID,
        string AccountSubControlID, string AccountHeadID,
        string CompanyID, string BranchID, string InvoiceNo,
        string UserID, string Credit, string Debit,
        DateTime TransacctionDate, string TransactionTitle)
    {
        if (dtEntries == null)
        {
            dtEntries = new DataTable();
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("FinancialYearID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("AccountControlID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("AccountSubControlID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("AccountHeadID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("CompanyID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("BranchID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("InvoiceNo");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("UserID");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("Credit");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("Debit");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("TransacctionDate");
            dtEntries.Columns.Add("TransactionTitle");
        }

        if (dtEntries != null)
        {
            dtEntries.Rows.Add(
                FinancialYearID,
                AccountControlID,
                AccountSubControlID,
                AccountHeadID,
                CompanyID,
                BranchID,
                InvoiceNo,
                UserID,
                Credit,
                Debit,
                TransacctionDate,
                TransactionTitle);

        }
    }
}

Query of inserting data in transaction table
foreach (DataRow entryrow in dtEntries.Rows)
            {
                string entryquery = string.Format("insert into tblTransaction(FinancialYearID,AccountHeadID,AccountControlID,AccountSubControlID,UserID,InvoiceNo,Credit,Debit,TransectionDate,TransactionTitle,CompanyID,BranchID) " +
                                    "values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')",
                                    Convert.ToString(entryrow[0]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[1]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[2]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[3]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[4]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[5]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[6]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[7]), (entryrow[8]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[9]), CompanyID, BranchID);
                DatabaseQuery.Insert(entryquery);
            }

Another other query of inserting the payment details is works perfect.
IF any addition information need please let me know.

Yikes... this is crazy vulnerable to sql injection issues. It's practically begging to get hacked.

You have debugged that code seen that you get to the creation of the insert statement and looked into DatabaseQuery.Insert what it does with it as we can't.

include code for DatabaseQuery... you should be using prepared/parameter-ized statements to secure against injections.  (or just keep things simple and inside the framework by using LINQ statements/entity... I assume there's a reason you can't do that here?)

Aside: Do you mind if code like ... + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + DateTime.Now.Millisecond; uses two different values for now? It's often much easier to interpret database activity when a single date/time value is used for all of the related activity, i.e. capture the value of DateTime.Now at the start of the method and use that value throughout.

@HABO no no DateTime.Now store in specific format and at the last i try to retrieve a milliseconds not the complete date and time.

@TimirBhingradiya The point is that the second call to DateTime.Now might return the milliseconds from a different month. It just takes one clock tick between calls for any part of the date/time to change. If you start with DateTime now = DateTime.Now; and then format pieces/parts from now you are guaranteed that nothing interesting will happen. Or you could use the milliseconds format in ToString and do it in one step.

@HABO yes but the issue i faced that interstation of data in the database. there is nothing issue with this ... + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")

That date might not be a problem. But TransectionDate should be one. You can't just expect that Convert.ToString() does the right thing. It will format stuff by your local culture settings. Those are of no interest to your database it has its own culture neutral format requirements. Database Parameters handle of of it but with your DatabaseQuery class design you ignored all of this. That class is a failure. We might help when seeing it but without its already obvious that one is a dead end.

Can you post the database table schema - are all the columns really strings? Did you get an exception or did it really just "not insert"? To debug, print out the SQL statement and try and run that directly in the database. But I can't emphasise enough all the comments above that you should absolutely not, ever, emphatically never, be formatting a string containing SQL to run: use a parameterised query.

 foreach (DataRow entryrow in dtEntries.Rows)
        {
            string entryquery = string.Format("insert into tblTransaction(FinancialYearID,AccountHeadID,AccountControlID,AccountSubControlID,UserID,InvoiceNo,Credit,Debit,TransectionDate,TransactionTitle,CompanyID,BranchID) " +
                                "values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')",
                                Convert.ToString(entryrow[0]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[1]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[2]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[3]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[4]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[5]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[6]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[7]), (entryrow[8]), Convert.ToString(entryrow[9]), CompanyID, BranchID);
            DatabaseQuery.Insert(entryquery);
        }


Here you are making all are string type that not properly converted to db column types
Please check the column datatype so that it will not fail the insertion

